# Назвать переменную по имени файла (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Открываю файл

```
pd.read_csv('courses.csv')
```

Нужно чтобы переменная, в которую открываю файл сама назвалась по имени файла, то есть чтобы получилось

```
courses = pd.read_csv('courses.csv')
```

Но чтобы имя переменной присвоилось автоматически (так как файлов много и вручную называть переменные долго). Не могу найти решение.

Comment: Называть переменные по какому-либо условию во время выполнения кода - неверный подход. Во-первых, у питона нет стандартных способов для этого - приходится обращаться к словарю с определением глобальных переменных, а во-вторых - это часто ведет к путанице и делает код непрозрачным. Ниже вам дали ответ, как работать с именами файлов через словарь - это лучший вариант решения вашей проблемы.

Comment: А в чем неверность подхода, можете подробнее объяснить? Чем вариант со словарем плох?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable В смысле кодозатратности вы ничего не выигрываете. а вот с эффективностью, отладкой, надежностью - проигрываете.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь словарем:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path(r"C:\full\path\to\courses.csv")

res = {}

res[filename.stem] = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

после этого можно обращаться к словарю по имени файла:

```
print(res["courses"])
print(res["another_csv_filename_without_extension"])
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В принципе так можно сделать например через globals["courses"] = ... и тогда появится глобальная переменная courses с присвоенным вами значением. Но лучше так не делать, а сделать как в другом ответе - словарь, где будут собраны все ваши данные. Так с ними и работать удобнее, когда они все в одном словаре.